# How to create dynamic xpath using for loop in nodejs cucumber selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium, cucumber, webdriver-io

How to create dynamic `xpath` using `for` loop in nodejs(selenium), for example:

```
List<WebElement>colHeader= rowVals.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("th"));
System.out.println("Header values:");
for(int i=0; i<colHeader.size(); i++){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody[@id='se-tbody-result']//tr["+ i + //a"));
}
```

I would like to convert above mentioned code in nodejs for fething data using `xpath`

Comment: You're missing `"` before `//a` and there's some extra `|` at end of line

Answer (score 0):

avoid formatting literals using

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//tbody[@id='se-tbody-result']//tr[${i}]//a`));
```

now you dont want to include ",+ for formatting

[image]